# How to change Ag-Grid header size?

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid

I want to use relative units (such "vh") to set size of a table header. I can't use css, because Ag-Grid adds inline style "height" in *.ag-header* and *.ag-header-overlay*.

```
gridOptions.headerHeight = null
```

didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you set it programmatically by Javascript?

```
var x= 10  //for ex. if you want 10vh    
gridOptions.headerHeight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight *(x/100.00);

//Event listener to set header height on resize

        object.addEventListener("resize", function(){
           var x= 10
           myGrid.setHeaderHeight(document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight *(x/100.00))
        }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I hoped for a built-in option, but your solution is good too.

Comment: can you please set it as answer if it pleases you? Regards

Answer (score -1):

Seems you don't read the documentation:

*"headerHeight  The height for the row containing the column label header. If not specified the default is 25px."*

/* Group columns */
groupHeaderHeight:75,

/* Label columns */
headerHeight: 150,

/* Floating filter */
floatingFiltersHeight:50,

/* Pivoting, requires turning on pivot mode. Label columns */
pivotGroupHeaderHeight:50,

/* Pivoting, requires turning on pivot mode. Group columns */
pivotGroupHeaderHeight:100,

Comment: My question is about using relative(not absolute such px) units. *headerHeight* set size in px. I need other units or way to disable default value and set sizes in css